# Не работает авторизация в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужна помощь, что не так? Вроде срабатывает, но не авторизуется.

**User.php:**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "blg_user".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $surname
 * @property string $name
 * @property string $password
 * @property string $salt
 * @property string $access_token
 * @property string $create_data
 *
 * @property BlgBlog[] $blgBlogs
 * @property BlgComment[] $blgComments
 */
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'blg_user';
    }

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username', 'surname', 'name', 'password'], 'required'],
        [['username'], 'unique'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'username' => 'Username',
        'surname' => 'Surname',
        'name' => 'Name',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'salt' => 'Salt',
        'access_token' => 'Access Token',
        'create_data' => 'Create Data',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getBlgBlogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlgBlog::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getBlgComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlgComment::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne(['id' => $id]);
}

public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}

public static function findByUsername($username)
{
    return static::findOne(['username' => $username]);
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryKey()['id'];
}

public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->access_token;
}

public function validateAuthKey($authkey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authkey;
}

public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return $this->password;
}

}
```

Вроде все правильно сделал, пользователь сохраняется в базу данных.

**sitecontroller.php:**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionIndex()
{
    return $this->render('index');
}

public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();

    return $this->goHome();
}

public function actionContact()
{
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

        return $this->refresh();
    }
    return $this->render('contact', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

public function actionAbout()
{
    return $this->render('about');
}
}
```

**Loginform.php:**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    private $_user = false;


/**
 * @return array the validation rules.
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

/**
 * Validates the password.
 * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
 *
 * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
 * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds user by [[username]]
 *
 * @return User|null
 */
public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
}
```

Comment: Что именно происходит у вас, как понять "не авторизуется"?

Comment: Можете предоставить код формы, которую вы отправляете

Comment: спасибо всем,уже разобрался

Comment: А проблема то решилась?
А то я с тем же столкнулся